# Signed number multiplication on FPGA

Tags: fpga, vhdl, computer-arithmetic

I am trying to multiply signed numbers on a Nexys A7-100T FPGA development board with VHDL.

See [Reference manual webpage link](https://reference.digilentinc.com/reference/programmable-logic/nexys-a7/start) for the FPGA board hardware information.

Also see this link (begins page 78) for Vivado's [Vivado design synthesis guide](https://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/sw_manuals/xilinx2016_4/ug901-vivado-synthesis.pdf) user VGDL guide which shows how to use the hardware multiplier logic.

I know this will work for unsigned numbers but can this be used for signed numbers with some additional logic / code?

I also have looked at the complex multiplier within this document however I am totally unfamiliar with the concept behind it?

How do people use the multiplier hardware to multiply signed numbers?

Comment: It is same as unsigned multiplication. Declare the signal as `signed` and use `*` . Complex multiplication in that UG shows how to use the pre-adder, acc and other stuff in the DSP. if you don't code for those, it will just do the multiplication.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Vivado synthesiser is smart. You have to declare the operands as `signed`. If the operands are unsigned, explicitly type cast all of them to `signed` and then simply multiply using `*`. It should infer a signed DSP multiplier on synthesis.

If it's not inferring automatically (can be due to multiple reasons), then you may have to use `USE_DSP` attribute to force the synthesiser to map the multiplication logic to DSP slice.

[Page 61, Vivado Synthesis Guide](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/sw_manuals/xilinx2018_3/ug901-vivado-synthesis.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwiWmZq3wvrtAhV3xTgGHR3GDJ0QFjAAegQIARAB&usg=AOvVaw0G7uhe4a10ZBBtPHrLbtIX)

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if it's (even close to) the best way, but when I needed to do this, I checked the signs of the two numbers, ran that through an XOR, and stashed it in a flop. Then I took the absolute values of both operands, multiplied those, and then if my saved bit from the XOR was set, negated the result.